# compiler errors in atlconv.h,atliface.h in VC MFC program

Tags: mfc, atl

I have a VC++ MFC COM component developed in VC++6.0 earlier. Now my pc has installed with VS 2005 and VS 2010.

Now I have a new changes to my old code which i built in VC++6.0, I have opened VC++6.0 and trying to run the application then i am receiving errors in **compiler errors in atlconv.h in VC++ MFC program** atliface.h #define #endif errors etc.,

Is the installation of newer versions corrupted atl files by any chance. How do i overcome these atl errors? please suggest me.

thanks in advance.

Regards,
Rajeswari.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is some changes in ATL/MFC that prevent a straightforward compilation of the old Visual Studio 6 compiling code in newer Visual Studio versions. This link may help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/686cfhy4(v=vs.71).aspx. If it is an emergency situation you probably get a faster solution by installing VC 6 in XPMode.

Comment: Thank you for your response but i am compiling my code in same Visual studio 6.0 only..My PC is also window XP same old.